# Creating a JS function and specifying its scope?

Tags: javascript

I had a random, rather rudimentary question pop into my head as I was writing some JS about scopes and closures. (Please bear with me with the rather convoluted example.)

Let's say I have two functions, one that's more or less a decorator called "makeMagicFn". This thing takes in an object, looks up the `randomFn` method on it, and does something cool to it, attaching it as a property to a new object as `someSpecialFn`, returning the object.

The second function is where that magic happens. It has a few local variables inside of it, and then defines the "random" function for use in the `makeMagicFn` described above.

Here's the fun part. The `randomFn`, defined here as `innerFn`, looks up the variables defined on `outerFn`'s scope (`foo` and `baz`), and does some stuff with them. At the end, the decorated `innerFn` is returned from `outerFn` to be used by its caller.

```
function makeMagicFn({ randomFn }) {
  const someSpecialFn = makeSomethingAwesomeWithRandomFn(fn);
  return {someSpecialFn};
}

function outerFn() {
  const foo = "bar";
  const baz = "qux";

  const insideFn = () => {
    console.log(foo, baz);
  }
  
  const {someSpecialFn} = makeMagicFn({ randomFn: insideFn });


  return someSpecialFn;
}
```

Now for my question.

Does JS allow me to define `innerFn` outside of `outerFn`, in such a way that allows access to `outerFn`'s scope, so it can look up the variables without throwing a `___ is not defined` error? (E.g. if I wanted to import it from a separate file instead.) Like using `.bind`, except setting the context not on `outerFn`'s `this`, but its place in memory instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Local variables are local, and scope is lexical. To create a closure over them, you must define the function where they are in scope.

You can do lots of trickery if you don't make `foo` and `baz` local variables but properties of an object, which you then can pass around (in the easiest case, as an argument to `makeMagicFn`).

Comment: Bummer. Thanks! Appreciate it :)